# Using AutoIt functions with Python

Tags: python, com, autoit

I am new to using AutoIt, and I am trying to use it to automatically click buttons on Windows programs.  I have been able to access some functions using `import win32com.client` and `win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")`.

But I am wondering if anyone knows of another way of doing this without downloading something else.  The thing is, I had to download Pywin32 to do this.  Is there something within the native Python libraries that can use AutoIt or its COMs module to run the functions?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you can use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html). For example, follow code sends message `Hello` to active window:

```
from ctypes import windll
path = r"C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\AutoItX\AutoItX3.dll"
autoit = windll.LoadLibrary(path)
autoit.AU3_Send(u"Hello{!}", 0)
```

Also, you can run `autoit` scripts by using `os.system` or `subprocess.call` modules.
With `os.system`:

```
import os
os.system(r'lowerchange.au3')
```

With `subprocess.call`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\AutoIt3.exe',r'lowerchange.au3'])
```